# How to generate PDF from scratch, pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf-generation

I need more options than third party pdf-generation libraries provide. Is it possible to generate a pdf file without using any js frameworks (server-side or client-side)?

I know there are lots of pdf-generation frameworks. I tried couple of them. But they are not enough for my project to be well optimized. I want to learn whether it's possible using pure js or not. If not, then which framework has the most options for aligning, working with columns, controlling page count etc.

I am kinda looking for a Microsoft Word like editing capability.

Also I'll be apprecited if you can teach me the logic behind the pdf-generation frameworks. I couldn't find any information about it.

**UPDATE:** For now, I figured out how Chrome's own pdf exporter works (Ctrl+P). And reorganized my code to build a well aligned, printable html document. Unfortunately it only works appropriately on chrome. But it works :). Now I am able to print whatever I wrote in html.